# Which Date format does Android's Telephony API use?

Tags: java, android, telephony

Thanks for reading my question.

Im attempting to read the date of a SMS message from Android's telephony API. I've been testing on my phone, and my friend just sent me a text message. I assumed its a UTC timestamp, but a few things seem off.

1. It's negative. And the message was just sent and received.
2. It's rather short for a UTC timestamp.

Here's what Im currently getting - `-1063901466`

Any advice into how to convert this to a useable date is definitely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Silly mistake. I was pulling it from the cursor as an int

`inboxCursor.getInt(inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date"));`

and it should be

`inboxCursor.getString(inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date"));`